# bcrypt compare with nodejs

Tags: node.js, backend, bcrypt, mern

So im getting this error
`Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined`
and this is the code

```
    router.post('/loguser', async (req, res) => {
        const compareHashed = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password)
        const user = await User.findOne({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: compareHashed
        })
        if (user) {
            console.log('user is found')
        }
        if (!user) {
            console.log('user is not found')
        }
    })
```

does anyone know how to fix this, I know its a problem with bcrypt

Comment: You should get the user first by username.
Then you should compare your password with user password.
bcyrpt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, data) => {
// your callback
})

Comment: Can you tell us what were you trying to do here so that it helps write a better answer for you?

Comment: You need to pass 2 things to bcrypt.compare -- how else will you say what 2 things you are comparing?

Comment: @douscriptist you don't have to specify a callback function -- in which case you get a Promise back you an `await` as @evan_tech1234 is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi bro first we hashed password and stored in db right

retrieve that hashed password from db and compare it with actual password

for eg: if we trying to login with email and password

```
    User.find({email:req.body.email}).exec().then(result=>{

  if(result.length < 1){
    console.log('email not found')
  }else{
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,result[0].password,(err,result)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log('password not match')
      }
      if(result){
        console.log('password match')
      }
    })
  }
})
```